# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1 ..... to type 'DatabaseModel1......'. ASP

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Hi im trying to assign a default group to any user that registers with my site. Since the admin Id of that group is the administrator, I query my database for a group with a admin id of my administrator and then assign that group to the user. However the following error is being thrown
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[DatabaseModel1.Group]' to type 'DatabaseModel1.Group'. "
Heres the code

```
        Dim defaultGroup = (From group As Group In context.Groups
                     Where group.AdminID = ((From users As User0 In context.User0
                                            Where users.Name Like "Administrator"
                                            Select users.UserID).First)
                       Select group)

        currentUser.Groups.Add(defaultGroup)//the error is being thrown here
```

any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a query which can return multiple results, but you're trying to assign it to a *single-value* variable.

You probably just need to use something like:

```
currentUser.Groups.Add(defaultGroup.First)
```

The probable options are:

- `First()` - allows multiple results and returns the first; will throw an exception if there are none
- `FirstOrDefault()` - allows multiple results and returns the first; will return the default value for the element type (e.g. `null`) if there are no results
- `Last()` - allows multiple results and returns the last; will throw an exception if there are none
- `LastOrDefault()` - allows multiple results and returns the last; will return the default value for the element type (e.g. `null`) if there are no results
- `Single()` - expects exactly one result; if there are no results or mulitple results, an exception is thrown

Now that you've shown the query, it sounds like you should probably use a join rather than a nested query. I'm not hot on the VB query syntax, but in C# you might want:

```
var defaultGroupQuery = 
        from group in context.Groups
        join user in context.User0 on group.AdminID equals user.UserID
        where user.Name == "Administrator"
        select group;
```

Comment: Damn... can't believe I fell for this for a second time.  Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<int> adminIDs = context.User0.Where(u=> u.Name.Contains("Administrator"))
                               .Select(u=>u.UserId);

    //you can use `FirstOrDefault()` above and it will return only int not `List<int>`
    // but i'm showing you how to get all IDs then you can get the first one

    int adminId = adminIDs.FirstOrDefault();

    //and then get only one Group using this adminID
    var defaultGroup = context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.AdminID == adminId);
    if(defaultGroup != null)
    {
      currentUser.Groups.Add(defaultGroup);
    }

    //you can use the `List<int> adminIDs` if you need to get all admin groups

var groups = context.Groups.Where(gg => adminIDs.Contains(gg.AdminID));
```

Hope it helps.